# Trying to read a JSON file with a JS script in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am trying to use my json file, `busesNotArrived.json` and put its contents in a `<p>`, however it is not working and the data in the JSON file is not displaying, here is my code:

```
<p>Buses Not Arrived:<br><br><span id="output"></p>

<script>
  const fs = require('fs')
  fs.readFile('json/busesNotArrived.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
      if (err) {
          alert('Error reading Database:', err)
          return
      }
      try {
          const bus = JSON.parse(jsonString)
          alert("Bus address is:", bus.busNumber)
          document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = bus.BusNumber;
  } catch(err) {
          alert('Error parsing JSON string:', err)
      }
  })
</script>
```

Inside of my JSON file, this is what is stored:

```
{
    "busRoute": 123123,
    "busNumber": 123123
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I eventually figured it out, so like what @Ronnel said, you cannot use `require()` because that is node.js and not javascript, so you would have to use the `fetch()` api to get the `.json` file.

For anyone who would like to see the code, here it is:

```
<div id="myData" class='absolute1' onclick='notArrived()'><strong><u>Not Yet Arrived</u></strong><br><br></div>

<script>
        fetch('json/busesNotArrived.json')
              .then(function (response) {
                  return response.json();
              })
              .then(function (data) {
                  appendData(data);
              })
              .catch(function (err) {
                  console.log('error: ' + err);
              });
          function appendData(data) {
              var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  div.innerHTML = 'Bus Number: ' + data[i].busNumber + "<br>" + 'Bus Route:' + ' ' + data[i].busRoute + "<br><br>";
                  mainContainer.appendChild(div);
              }
          }

</script>
```

|| Sorry about the Indents :P ||

And also, here is what was in the `.json` file so you can work off of it:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "busNumber": "4024",
        "busRoute": "44444"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "busNumber": "4044",
        "busRoute": "4444"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "busNumber": "5024",
        "busRoute": "55555"
    }
]
```

Good Luck using this!

[If you wanted more explanation, here is where I got the code from:](https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/)

(`https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/`)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not the same as node.js
require() is not a part of JavaScript standard and is not supported by browsers out of the box, it is the node.js module system.

You might need to directly include the modules; some of the modules might not work in the browser sandbox context.

Also, tools such as http://browserify.org/ might be useful.

And please put the error message too.

Comment: There is no error message, it just runs as normal, but without the JSON data.

Comment: "tools such as http://browserify.org/ might be useful" — They won't. Browsers provide no APIs that would make `fs` usable.

Comment: Console.log the json parse lemme see whats in there

Comment: Alright, Here is the output: `Bus address is: 123123`. I used the same code but put it into its own file.

Comment: What's your discord do you have wait let me do fix see i'll code wait ok.

Comment: KAYDEN#6839 my discord accept me

Comment: Alright, give me a second to accept.